# Unable to access application in Application Registration Portal after creation of Azure Web App Bot

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a **Web App Bot** via the **Azure Portal** for the company I'm working for.

I currently have the **Contributor** role in the **Resource Group** where the **Web App Bot** resource is created.

After the deployment of the resource, I wanted to manage the *AppID* and *AppPassword* of the application so I clicked on the "*Manage*" link in the "*Bot Management>Settings*" section of the **Web App Bot** resource.

[image: Manage link]

This link redirected me to the **[Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)** where I received the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Therefore, am I missing some **permissions** to be able to see the application in the **Application Registration Portal** ?

And, as I created the **Web App Bot** resource, shouldn't I be the **owner** of the application allowing me to see it in the portal ?

Unfortunately the error message does not provide a lot of information on how to solve that issue.
Fortunately I was able to retrieve the *AppID* and *AppPassword* in the "*App Service Settings>Application Settings*" section of the Azure resource but I still can't access and manage the application in the Registration Portal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user accessing https://portal.azure.com/ is not assigned as "Owner" at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ for your application.

[image: Owners at apps.dev]

Ask your Azure Active Directory Tenant Administrator to review the application from the list at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList and request to add your account as additional "Owner".
Alternatively ask some other user (yourself with other account?) who is now the default Owner if you can find out who it is?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue has been solved after opening a Support Ticket. According to Microsoft, it's a known issue due to a Multi-tenant infrastructure.